# Nintendo Switch Games: Third-party services sharing definitions

Tags: nintendo-switch

My young child has a game which has established a sharing relationship with his "supervised" account. I got an email from Nintendo confirming this and went into the account to see what it says. From the "Settings for individual third party services" section, it says:

> Information received: Basic profile

I cannot find a definition of "Basic profile" anywhere. I can make some assumptions about that, but I'd prefer to know the exact legal definition that Nintendo uses.

Does anyone know where this stuff is defined? Searching the internet for the string "basic information" along with "nintendo" and "sharing" isn't exactly very targeted. :(

Answer (score 1):

Basic profile for nintendo is the profile name and any other info on the icon page when you tap the bubble that has the account info. So if you made the account its everything you inputted in the feilds whether they were true or not. I might add that when making the account you agree with third parties having access to that information if you hit the agree prompt for each game.